# Number of automorphisms on alternating group $A_n$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

How do I find the number of automorphisms of the alternating group on $n$ symbols $A_n$? I have found it for cyclic groups. But I have no idea how to do it here. In particular, I was asked to find it for $n=4 $. Please help me. I'll be thankful if to you if you suggest me how to approach and what I should read again.

Comment: See, for example, [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphisms_of_the_symmetric_and_alternating_groups)

Comment: I'm final year undergraduate student. I don't know the concept of outer automorphisms. And thank you for quick link.

Comment: You should look that up, it's fundamental to the notion of automorphism groups.  The key point is that the Inner automorphisms (those induced by conjugation) form a normal subgroup of $Aut(G)$. The outer automorphism group is the quotient.

Comment: Note:  the automorphism groups for symmetric and alternating groups are a rather technical topic..though the final result (at least for large enough $n$) is simple enough.  (But the exotic automorphism of $S_6$ is worth a lengthy story on its own). I'd think it was much more important to learn basic notions (like inner and outer automorphisms) first.